# Verification of function calls with Iterator parameters

Tags: scala, specs2

I have a function, which takes an `Iterator[T]` as a parameter which I want to validate in my test.

```
there was one(myMock).foo(List(<some_data_here>).iterator)
```

That test obviously fails if underlying iterator types doesn't matches. Also values couldn't be checked with regular matchers.
Is it possible to withdraw the arguments of the function calls to match them in regular way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ArgumentCaptor` from Mockito.

First, create a helper method:

```
def captor[T: ClassTag]: ArgumentCaptor[T] = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]])
```

it is not required but I think looks nicer when you use it.

Then, setup your mock like this:

```
val myList = captor[Iterator[Int]]
myMock.foo(myList.capture) returns 7
```

Finally, to check the argument that was passed:

```
myList.getValue // this will be the argument that was passed to `foo`
```

having this value you can do assertions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I've red it just right now.

Comment: Hopefully I've solved my issue with CustomMatchers facilities.